# How to prove that the normal mode eigenvalue problem constitutes that of a Hermitian operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, operators

I am physics PhD student working on quantisation of electromagnetic fields in a non-homogeneous media. I am working through a paper at the moment and I am struggling with one of the statements. In the paper, there is a time independent eigenvalue problem obtained from inserting a sum of exponential functions of time into the Maxwell equations.

> $$\pmb{\nabla}\times\left(\frac{\pmb{\nabla}\times\pmb{B}_m(\pmb{r})}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\right) = \frac{\omega_m^2}{c^2}\pmb{B}_m(\pmb{r})$$

The text calls this a "second order Hermitian eigenvalue problem". I am unsure how to demonstrate that this problem is Hermitian and would like some help, I will attach the paper below for clarity but only the relevant couple of pages as it was sent to me by my supervisor and I am don't think it is appropriate to distribute the whole thing. I first tried establishing an inner product integrating over a large box of volume $V$ with periodic boundary conditions.

> $$\hat{O}(\pmb{Y}) =  \pmb{\nabla}\times\left(\frac{\pmb{\nabla}\times\pmb{Y}(\pmb{r})}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\right)
> \\
> (\pmb{X},\hat{O}\pmb{Y}) = \iiint_{V}d^3\pmb{r} \pmb{X}\cdot\hat{O}(\pmb{Y}) = \iiint_{V}d^3\pmb{r} \pmb{X}\cdot\pmb{\nabla}\times\left(\frac{\pmb{\nabla}\times\pmb{Y}(\pmb{r})}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\right)$$

I then tried to find the components of the operator $\hat{O}$ acting on $\pmb{Y}$ to determine the inner product. I have used implicit summation over repeated symbols.

> $$\left[\pmb{\nabla}\times\left(\frac{\pmb{\nabla}\times\pmb{Y}(\pmb{r})}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\right)\right]_k = \epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{1}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\left[\pmb{\nabla}\times\pmb{Y}(\pmb{r})\right]_j\right) = \epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\frac{1}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\epsilon_{mnj}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_m} Y_n(\pmb{r})\right)
>     \\
>     = -\epsilon_{jik}\epsilon_{jmn}\left(-\frac{2}{n^3(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial Y_n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_m}  + \frac{1}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial^2 Y_n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_i\partial x_m} \right)
>     \\
>     = -\left(\delta_{im}\delta_{kn} - \delta_{in}\delta_{km}\right)\left(-\frac{2}{n^3(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial Y_n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_m}  + \frac{1}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial^2 Y_n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_i\partial x_m} \right)
>     \\
>     = \frac{2}{n^3(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_m}\frac{\partial Y_k(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_m} - \frac{1}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial^2 Y_k(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_m\partial x_m} - \frac{2}{n^3(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_n}\frac{\partial Y_n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_k} + \frac{1}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial Y_n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_n}$$

From here I tried to integrate the inner product of another vector function with this vector function.

> $$(\pmb{X},\hat{O}\pmb{Y}) = \iiint_{V}d^3\pmb{r} \pmb{X}\cdot\pmb{\nabla}\times\left(\frac{\pmb{\nabla}\times\pmb{Y}(\pmb{r})}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\right)
> \\
> =  \iiint_{V}d^3\pmb{r} X_k\left(\frac{2}{n^3(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_m}\frac{\partial Y_k(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_m} - \frac{1}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial^2 Y_k(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_m\partial x_m} - \frac{2}{n^3(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_n}\frac{\partial Y_n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_k} + \frac{1}{n^2(\pmb{r})}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial Y_n(\pmb{r})}{\partial x_n}\right)$$

I want to demonstrate:

> $$(\pmb{X},\hat{O}\pmb{Y}) = (\pmb{Y},\hat{O}^*\pmb{X})$$
> So it tried to do this by parts but it won't work due to the reciprocal of the refractive index, $n$. Are there any other ways I can prove this, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which paper? Which page?

Comment: Apologies I mis-spoke it is a PhD thesis called "Quantum and Classical Optics of Dispersive and Absorptive Structured Media" by Navin Bhat that I have been told to work through. It is on pages 21 to 22. As I said I don't think it appropriate to promulgate the paper as it was sent to me by my supervisor and the question has been answered anyway both below and subsequently by my supervisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original answer was misleading -- at least for the B equation. Consider the vector identity
$$
\nabla \cdot ({\bf a}\times {\bf b})= {\bf b}\cdot (\nabla\times {\bf a})- {\bf a} \cdot (\nabla \times {\bf b})
$$
with ${\bf b}=n^{-2} \nabla \times {\bf v}$:
$$
\nabla \cdot \left({\bf u} \times \left(\frac 1 {n^2} \nabla\times {\bf v}\right)\right)= \frac 1 {n^2}(\nabla\times {\bf u})\cdot (\nabla\times {\bf v})- {\bf u}\cdot (\nabla \times \frac 1 {n^2}(\nabla \times {\bf v}))
$$
The $u,v$ symmetry  shows that, discarding boundary terms
$$
\int {\bf u}\cdot \left (\nabla \times \frac 1 {n^2}( \nabla \times {\bf v})\right) d^3x = \int{\bf v}\cdot \left(\nabla \times \frac 1 {n^2}( \nabla \times {\bf u})\right).
$$
so
$$
O \equiv  \nabla\times\left( \frac 1{n^2}\nabla\,\,\times\right.
$$
is hermitian with the usual inner product.  I supect that
$$
\nabla\times \left(\nabla\,\times \frac 1{n^2}\right.
$$
is hermitian wrt to the inner product with the $1/n^2$, but it's time for my bath....  OK Hyporntex distracted me from my bath.

We also have
$$
\nabla \cdot \left(\frac 1{n^2} {\bf D}_1 \times \left(  \nabla\times \frac 1{n^2}{\bf D}_1\right)\right)= \frac 1 {n^2}(\nabla\times \frac 1{n^2} {\bf D}_1)\cdot (\nabla\times \frac 1 {n^2}{\bf D}_2)- \frac 1 {n^2} {\bf D}_1\cdot (\nabla \times (\nabla \times \frac 1{n^2}{\bf D}_2))
$$
so the same algebra shows that
$$
\int \frac 1{n^2} {\bf D}_1\cdot \left( \nabla\times \nabla\times \frac 1{n^2}{\bf D}_2\right)d^3x =\int \frac 1{n^2} {\bf D}_2\cdot \left( \nabla\times \nabla\times \frac 1{n^2}{\bf D}_1\right)d^3x
$$
so that with
$$
\langle {\bf u},{\bf v}\rangle_n = \int \frac 1{n^2} {\bf u}\cdot {\bf v} d^3 x,
$$
the equation for the ${\bf D}$ is self adjoint. This is why the orthogonality
$$
\int {\bf D}_i^* \frac 1{n^2} {\bf D}_j d^3x = \delta_{ij}
$$ needs the $1/n^2$. Now it's time to cook supper....

Comment: I will give that a go, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I thought a bit about your suggestion. Firstly I am not sure why the inner product should have this extra reciprocal n term in it. Secondly, even with this inner product I still don't know how I can integrate it by parts as I cannot isolate the n terms. I understand if you are busy at the moment but if you are free later, I would really appreciate it if you could explain a bit more. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll add a bit to my answer.

Comment: I am surprised that the system can be shown to be Hermitean because it has been known since 1960's that a *lossless* (yes, $\epsilon, \mu$ are real) but inhomogeneously filled waveguide can have complex eigenvalues and with that propagating modes $e^{\mathfrak{j}(\omega t - \beta z)}$ such that the wavenumber $\beta$ is complex number. See, e.g., Clarricoats "COMPLEX MODES OF PROPAGATION IN DIELECTRIC LOADED CIRCULAR WAVEGUIDE", ELECTRONICS LETTERS July 1965 Vol. 1 No. 5, and Rozzi : "General Constraints on the Propagation of Complex Waves..." IEEE MTT VOL. 46, NO. 5, MAY 1998

Comment: @ hyporynex:  Do the complex ev's come from the boundary consitions?  I know that the BC's  for which the vector laplacaian is hermitian are rather restricted.

Comment: I will be careful with my answer because I admit that I never quite understood this business. I have seen (numerically) these waves but they can also be measured (backward waves). The waveguide itself is assumed to be of lossless conductor having singly or multiply connected cross section, homogeneous along the axis but inhomogeneously filled transversally. The circular guide with cylindrical symmetrical filling can be solved "analytically" (Bessel/Hankel/etc. functions and some such) and has the complex roots. My limited numerical experience is with the rectangular cross section kind.

Comment: @ hyportnex I can see that the $k$'s might be complex,  but I think that the ev's will  be standing waves with real frequencies and its the frequencies that are shown real by the self adjointness.  The BC's may still be a problem though. I just ignored them

Comment: How can $\beta$ ($\kappa$) be complex but the ev's will be standing waves with real frequencies, etc. Do you mean by this that we close the waveguide with a pair of electric walls and form a cavity and then the resonant frequencies will be real? Yes, that is probably true and this is what confuses me for what does it mean to have a complex $\beta$: they do show up as reactive terms at a discontinuity. But how could the differential system be selfadjoint for the cavity and not for the waveguide unless in the complex mode $\mathbf{E}_{\perp}=0$ ?

Comment: @mikestone Thank you for the answer that explains clarifies everything. The only thing, when you discard the surface integral of the cross product, does that mean it can be shown that it vanishes explicitly or you are considering integration over a large enough volume such that it vanishes anyway. Otherwise this would break the equality adjoint terms.

Comment: As I said to hyportnex, I did not consider the BC's required to make the boundary terms vanish.  For a perfect conductor and uniform $\epsilon$, they are the usual BC's of Maxwell fields at a metallic interface, and would imagine that they still work for non uniform $\epsilon$, but I do not know. For the uniform case you can look at page 252 in our book https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf

Comment: @mikestone Ah I see now, thank you for your help!